# Javascript RegEx to comment/un-comment PHP tags from file source

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have some issues and I need your help.

I'm using HTML5 FileReader to read the source of a file. After that i need to find all the  php tags and HTML comment(with slight modification) them (keeping the PHP tags) like:

```
<?php echo('2'); ?>
to
 <!--#<?php echo('2'); ?>#-->
```

and backwards.

this should work for both versions with `<? ?> and <?php ?>` format.

Another issue that may occur is when opening the processed file in the browser.I think the <,>,& will be html escaped so I need to keep that in mind on the un-comment function.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### For commenting

#### Regex

```
/<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]+?\?>/g
```

Javascript doesn't support the `s` modifier. I use a simple trick here for matching php blocks spanning over multiple lines: `[\s\S]+`. This character class will match any white characters and any non white characters.

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/cB0mO4

---

### For uncommenting

#### Regex

```
/<\?(?:php)?[\s\S]+?\?>/g
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### Demo

http://regex101.com/r/mU2tK1